# References on KKT Conditions applied to Calculus of Variations

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control, calculus-of-variations

I am looking for research references for KKT conditions and Slack Variables applied to variational calculus problems in things like Control Theory and such.

For example, naively I might try solving a problem like,

\begin{align}
\text{extremize}\ \ S[x] &= \int dt\ \mathcal{L}(x, \dot{x}) \\
\text{s.t.}\ &\ f(x) \ge 0
\end{align}

By adding slack variables and Lagrange multipliers,

\begin{align}
\text{extremize}\ \ S[x, \lambda, s] &= \int dt\ \mathcal{L}(x, \dot{x}) + \lambda(f(x) -
 s^2)\\
\end{align}
with $ x, \lambda, s $ being functions of time.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly "classical" references are the monographs

- [Convex analysis and variational problems](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971088) by Ekeland and Temam, and
- [Optimization by vector space methods](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-047118117X.html) by Luenberger,

which are also very suitable for your approach I think. There is also the more "modern" and very comprehensive

- [Perturbation analysis of optimization problems](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-1394-9) by Bonnans and Shapiro

and generally a lot more books on optimization in function spaces.

Answer (score 0):

For calculus of variations problems, one good reference for what your are looking for is

[Calculus of Variations](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486414485.html) by Gelfand and Fomin

For KKT conditions in optimal control, you may take a look at

[Applied Optimal Control: Optimization, Estimation and Control](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0891162283) by Bryson and Ho

[Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control Theory: A Concise Introduction](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9760.html) by Liberzon